# Max steps in lars

Tags: regression, lars

I don't know how many steps are necessary for `lars()` to select the variables till the algorithm proceeds to the saturated fit (especially using the `lars` package in `R`)? Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence in the second section of [The LARS paper](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~imj/WEBLIST/2004/LarsAnnStat04.pdf) says that the LARS algorithm requires $m$ steps, where $m$ is the number of covariates.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have seen that when the number of predictors(m) is much larger than the number of observations(n) in high dimensional data then lars gets at most n steps, but I am not sure how I can define the exact number of steps in order to have the saturated fit. Also is it possible to give me a hint how I can define the parameter lambda for lasso in order to have the saturated fit?(any document that explain it). thanks in advance